# Peoplesoft Test Framework Exists action

Tags: testing, automation, peoplesoft

How do you use the "Exists" action in Peoplesoft Test Framework? It does not work as documented. As documented, it says: for a Type of "Text", and an Action of "Exists", use a Recognition value of "name=XYZ;ret&exists" where XYZ is the name of an HTML element and where &exists will be set to true or false, depending on whether or not the element exists. This does not work. The only way it finds the element is if the Recognition value is "name=XYZ". It is not clear, and experimenting did not work, what the "Parameters" or "Values" columns should have.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Link** **Exists** in PTF. It will find the value of *page_name.component_name.gbl* and will redirect to that page.